# How to hide top navigation bar in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I need to hide nav bar on top in specific screens. How to achieve?. i am using react-navigation/material-top-tabs

I need to hide nav bar on top in specific screens. How to achieve?. i am using react-navigation/material-top-tabs

I need to hide nav bar on top in specific screens. How to achieve?. i am using react-navigation/material-top-tabs

```
//page 1  <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Connection">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Connection"
        component={UserScreen}
        options={{ unmountOnBlur: true }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>

//page2 <Tab.Navigator
          // screenOptions={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
          // screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          //   tabBarVisible: false,
          // })}
          initialRouteName="UserTabStack"
          tabBarOptions={{
            labelStyle: {
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "black",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="UserTabStack"
            //  component={UserList}
            component={UserTabStack}
            options={{ tabBarLabel: "Userlist" }}
            listeners={({ route }) => {
              setTabPage(route.name);
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="GroupList"
            // component={GroupList}
            component={GroupTabStack}
            options={{ tabBarLabel: "GroupList" }}
            listeners={({ route }) => {
              setTabPage(route.name);
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator> //page3  <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="UserList">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="UserList"
        component={UserList}
        options={{ unmountOnBlur: true }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AddConnection"
        component={AddUserScreen}
        options={{ unmountOnBlur: true }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Chat"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={{ unmountOnBlur: true }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: which version of react native navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens), you can hide the tab bar on specific screens by changing your navigation structure. In their example:

```js
function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The tab navigator is inside the first screen, and is the first component in your app's navigator. The following components are the two components that you don't want the top bar to be shown on, so in this example, Settings and Profile.

Answer (score 2):

set headerShown to false in Stack.Screen options

```js
<Stack.Screen
        name="UserList"
        component={UserList}
        options={{ unmountOnBlur: true, headerShown: false }}
      />
```